# Freeradius V3 meta-attributes. Check item attributes

Tags: freeradius

I am trying to migrate from version 2 to version 3.

The same unlang code worked in version 2. However in version 3 the same code does not work.

This is the error:

```
/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[406]: Failed parsing expanded string:

/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[406]: %{sql:SET @reset_date = '%{check:Reset-Date}'; SELECT IFNULL((sum(acctinputoctets)+sum(acctoutp... 

/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[406]:                            ^ Unknown module
```

If I remove `check` the parser does not throw errors.

Change `'%{check:Reset-Date}'` to `'%{Reset-Date}'`. However this will break my code, because `Reset-Date` is a radcheck attribute, stored in the radcheck table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's `control:Reset-Date`. We've never had `check` as a list qualifier.

Check items are specific to the users file and sql modules.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Can you please give me an example of how to use check?

Answer (score 0):

This how you can use control to check on expiry with expiration as an attribute

```
#expiration
    expiration{
        userlock = 1
        }
        if(userlock){
            update reply {
            Reply-Message := "Your account expired on %{control:Expiration}. Please refill your account to continue enjoying our service."
            }
            reject
        }
```

Now help us understand what you are trying to do.